# How would I keep a value between scenes?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I've been trying for a little bit here to set a muteSound boolean in my SoundManager and then to switch to a new scene and keep the value previously stored in muteSound but I'm unsuccessful.

I tried the DontDestroyOnLoad(this); in hopes that it'd bring it to the new scene but for some reason it isn't.

Would any of you know what my problem could be? Am I using the correct function?

Thanks,

Comment: That script is attached to an gameobject?

Comment: yes, it's attached to a prefab used in both scenes.

Comment: Where are you calling DontDestroyOnLoad(this)? you should call it on Start()

Comment: I was calling DontDestroyOnLoad(this) in the Start() of SoundManager but from what I read, the instance can't be there and would need to be in some other class like the GameManager.

Comment: simply use Player Prefs.  Programmer has explained it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some would say use `static`. That would work but avoid doing that as you will run into other problems. What you need is the `PlayerPrefs`. Save the value on exit. Read the value when game starts. You can do that in your `SoundManager`  script.

```
bool muteSound = false;

//Load the value when game starts (default is false)
void Start()
{
    muteSound = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("muteSound", 0));
}

int boolToInt(bool val)
{
    if (val)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

bool intToBool(int val)
{
    if (val != 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//Save on Exit
void OnDisable()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("muteSound", boolToInt(muteSound));
}
```

Comment: This I guess is more for in between game sessions, not for in between scenes.

Comment: @GunnarB. Why is it not for in between scenes? I know he asks for between scenes but I just saved him time for asking how to do this for the next game session. You usually  want to keep the player settings for next time the game starts again. That's like killing two birds with one stone.

Comment: Yes, a mute sound thing actually sounds like he want to save in between sessions too, so for that this is a good point.

Comment: Yes, this'd be for both sound and music to be separate. These are updated using a Toggle (Script) in a Unity game object.
I seem to have figured everything out and it does work but I'm wondering why I was told not to do the other way I posted. Perhaps you could elaborate why yours is preferred over mine?
I simply want to improve my knowledge that's all.

Comment: @Alox It's a good thing you want to know why.First, I want to say that the code in your answer will work. If you can do this without using static, go for it. In this case, your problem can be solved without using static so avoid using it. Less bug without static. Also, when the player ends the game and starts the game again, you want the settings to remain there, right? I would want the volume, the score, and all the other player settings to be saved. Your solution does not have that. `PlayerPrefs` can be used to save and read settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass a game object from scene to scene and all the values for classes assigned to that game object are maintained between scenes.

You basically just create an empty game object that stores your manager scripts and then pass the game object from scene to scene when you load them.  This should preserve the values for the scripts attached to the empty game object.

EDIT: Fixed some spelling/grammatical errors.

Answer (score -1):

Here was my solution:

```
public class SoundManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static SoundManager instance = null;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null) 
            instance = this; 
        else if (instance != this) 
            Destroy(gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

While I thought my problem was because of my changing the class to a singleton the actual problem was that there was another class that needed to be a singleton.

Since the rest of the code wouldn't be mine to share, [here is a tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/saving-data-between-scenes-in-unity/) which helped me understand what I was doing much better if anyone else ever runs into this type of problem.

Comment: I know this is a answer to your own question but you really should provide more info. Link only answers are discouraged and people visiting the site in the future with the same problem as you should be able to get enough information to solve it even if all links in the answer are dead. Just update the answer to include a few notes about some of the wrong ideas you had that the article cleared up and it should be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry about that, this is my first time asking a question, I'll edit it to have some key information from that link. Thanks :)

Comment: That bool can be part of your `SoundManager` only. It doesn't need to be in `GlobalControl` **IF** both scripts are on the same gameobject (in the scene)

Comment: Same gamobject or somehow part of the same parent, e.g. one being on the parent and one being on a child.

Comment: Do not do this, Alox.  Do what programmer explains.

Comment: Hmm, I got it working this way, care to explain why Programmer's solution is better? :o

Answer (score -1):

Instead of typing
`DontDestroyOnLoad(this);` type

```
void Awake() { 
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject); 
}
```

If this doesn't work I suggest you check out the [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

When the level is finished use
`PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("pref name", variable);` or `.SetInt();` or `.SetBool();`

And when the next level loads use
`value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("pref name");` or `.GetInt();` or `.GetBool();`

This player prefs can also be used as saves because they are stored inside the computers registry.
If you use this for loading things such as money and you are loading it for the first time, do this:

```
if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("money")) {

    money = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("money");
} else {

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("money", 0);
    money = 0;
}
```

If you don't do this the values can get messy a lot. I had **big** problems when I didn't use `PlayerPrefs.HasKey();`

Comment: `DontDestroyOnLoad(this)` and `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)` will do the same. If you call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on something the entire hierarchy that thing is part of will be preserved.

Comment: yea but he probably didn't call it in the Awake function.